# complete event of WizardStep not fired

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have setted a Wizard to work inside a Dialog; 
The problem is that the ***complete*** event of the WizardStep is not lunched (but the other event are launched without problems)

This is the Dialog fragment and the Controller:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
        xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">


    <Dialog title="Configura articoli colore" contentHeight="750px" contentWidth="600px">


        <Wizard>

            <WizardStep complete="wizardStepCompletedHandler" >
                    <MultiComboBox>
                        <core:Item key="0" text="0 - 0 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="1" text="1 - 0.1 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="2" text="2 - 0.2 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="3" text="3 - 0.3 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="4" text="4 - 0.4 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="5" text="5 - 0.5 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="6" text="6 - 0.6 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="8" text="8 - 0.8 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="9" text="9 - 0.9 mm"/>
                        <core:Item key="T" text="T - T mm"/>
                    </MultiComboBox>
            </WizardStep>

            <WizardStep>
                <MultiComboBox>
                    <core:Item key="big" text=" (>20kg)"/>
                    <core:Item key="mediam" text=" (4-5kg)"/>
                    <core:Item key="small" text=" (4-5kg)"/>
                    <core:Item key="very_small" text=" (1-3kg)"/>
                </MultiComboBox>
            </WizardStep>


        </Wizard>


        <endButton>
            <Button text="Close" press="onDialogCloseButton"/>
        </endButton>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

```js
ui5bp.confColorArticlesManager = {

    openDialog: function (oContext) {
        //var settingsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({versionServer:null});
        if (ui5bp.confColorArticlesManager.ContentWizard === undefined)
            ui5bp.confColorArticlesManager.ContentWizard = sap.ui.xmlfragment("ui5bp.view.fragment.ContentWizard", this);
        
        ui5bp.confColorArticlesManager.ContentWizard.open();
    },

    onDialogCloseButton: function (oEvent) {
        ui5bp.confColorArticlesManager.ContentWizard.close();
    },

    wizardStepCompletedHandler:function(oEvent){
        console.log();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.WizardStep.html#event:complete) `complete` event is fired when a step is finished.

It means, you need to add `complete="wizardStepCompletedHandler"` to every step you want this function to run after.

Like:

```
<Wizard>
<WizardStep complete="wizardStepCompletedHandler" >
//stuff
</WizardStep>
<WizardStep complete="wizardStepCompletedHandler" >
//stuff
</WizardStep>
<WizardStep complete="wizardStepCompletedHandler" >
//stuff
</WizardStep>
...
</Wizard>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/kusasiviha/edit?html,output) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because console.log() will not result in any output in the console, at least in chrome. From your coding it looks like it should work.